# How to generate PDF from an html page

Tags: php, html, forms, pdf

I have a form which is displayed using my custom plugin. 
Below given is code to display form using plugin:

```
$question = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name1 WHERE group_id=$id");
$instruction = $question[0]->instructions;
$html = "<h2>Instructions</h2><p>".$instruction."</p><br><button>Download</button>";
$arr_size = sizeof($question);
$html .= "<form method='POST' action=''>";
for ($i=0; $i < $arr_size ; $i++) { 
    $sid = $question[$i]->s_id;
    $html .= "<b>Question:</b><i><span>".$question[$i]->questions."</span></i><br>";
    $answer = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name2 WHERE u_id=$userid AND s_id=$sid");
    $size = sizeof($answer);
    $option = $question[$i]->options;
    for ($j=1,$k=0; $j <= $option; $j++,$k++) { 
        $html .= "<input type='hidden' value='".$answer[$k]->a_id."' name='aid".$sid.$j."'>";
        $html .= "<textarea name='ans".$sid.$j."' id='ans".$sid.$j."'>".$answer[$k]->answer."</textarea><br>";
    }
}
$html .= "<input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit2'></form>";
return $html;
```

Previous values submitted will be their in the text boxes. I need to download the contents of the form when I click the download button not on form submission.

Comment: Which pdf you used "Dompdf" ?

Comment: Hope this will help you. 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-convert-html-with-css-to-pdf-using-javascript

Comment: @Sandra, check this url i hope it's helpful :-
 http://w3init.com/php/libraries/generate-pdf-from-html-code-in-php-using-mpdf/  

AND 

https://www.phpflow.com/php/create-pdf-file-using-mpdf-php/

Comment: @Sandra, And i have "Dompdf" example if you want than i will post .?

Comment: @NimeShPatel can u post that example.

Comment: Please refer that link https://pdfcrowd.com/i/php-code-to-convert-html-to-pdf.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found answer for my question. First thing to do is download the pdf folder that you are using. Here I use MPDF. 
Here my html code for button:

```
<button class='pdfupload' id='".$userid."' dataoffset='".$group_id."'>Download</button>
```

From `$userid` and `$group_id` we will get the displayed form datas. In button click an ajax call is triggered.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.pdfupload').click(function(){
            var group_id = jQuery(this).attr('dataoffset');
            var ID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
            jQuery.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:"<?=site_url()?>/uploadpdf.php",
                data:{group_id:group_id, ID:ID},
                success:function(result){
                    window.location.replace('<?=site_url()?>/filegen.php?name='+result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

In ajax page the pdf will be generated. To generate pdf file mpdf.php need to be included. Below given is the code:

```
include('MPDF57/mpdf.php');
include 'wp-load.php';
global $wpdb;
$date = date("Ymdhis");
$filename = $id.'trialbasic'.$date.'.pdf';
$path = dirname(__FILE__).'/pdfs/'.$filename;
$html = "Your pdf content"; //Here in my code the details using `$userid` and `$group_id` will be fetched 
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output($path,'F');
echo $filename;
```

Here PDF file will be generate and stored in `$path`. The return of ajax will be the name of the PDF file. In the success part `filegen.php` is called in order to directly download the PDF file on click. The result of ajax will be passed to `filegen.php` The code in `filegen.php` is given below:

```
include 'wp-load.php';
$name = $_GET['name']; 
$path = dirname(__FILE__).'/pdfs/'.$name;
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $name);  // Make the browser display the Save As dialog
readfile($path);  //this is necessary in order to get it to actually download the file, otherwise it will be 0Kb
```

Finally thanks all for sparing your time to help me.

Comment: Is it possible to install MPDF without access to the terminal or package manager?

Comment: @posfan12 I uploaded the MPDF folder direct to my project folder. So I'm not sure whether its possible to install MPDF without package manager access.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that code

https://www.phpgang.com/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-in-php-with-fpdf_447.html?doing_wp_cron=1514545193.9442338943481445312500

You have to download fpdf library and  include it in your PHP file below settings and how to show tags, fonts and images in your pdf file. With fpdf library we used HTMLparser library contributed by programmers and all other libraries available here you can download and use as per your requirement.

index.html :

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>How to create Contact Form using Bootstrap  | PGPGang.com</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>How to create Contact Form using Bootstrap example.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;=> <a href="https://www.phpgang.com/">Home</a> | <a href="http://demo.phpgang.com/">More Demos</a></h2>
<div class="container">
      <form class="contact-us form-horizontal" action="actionpdf.php" method="post">
        <legend>Fill Form and submit to generate PDF</legend>        
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Url</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-globe"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" id="url" class="input-xlarge" name="url" placeholder="http://www.example.com">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Comment</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></span>
                    <textarea name="comment" class="span4" rows="4" cols="80" placeholder="Comment (Max 200 characters)"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button>
          </div>    
        </div>
      </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

actionpdf.php

```
require('WriteHTML.php');

$pdf=new PDF_HTML();

$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 15);

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('logo.png',18,13,33);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
$pdf->WriteHTML('<para><h1>PHPGang Programming Blog, Tutorials, jQuery, Ajax, PHP, MySQL and Demos</h1><br>
Website: <u>www.phpgang.com</u></para><br><br>How to Convert HTML to PDF with fpdf example');

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',7); 
$htmlTable='<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD>Name:</TD>
<TD>'.$_POST['name'].'</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>Email:</TD>
<TD>'.$_POST['email'].'</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>URl:</TD>
<TD>'.$_POST['url'].'</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>Comment:</TD>
<TD>'.$_POST['comment'].'</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>';
$pdf->WriteHTML2("<br><br><br>$htmlTable");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',6);
$pdf->Output(); 
?>
```

Comment: I need to generate PDF on button click not on form submission.

Comment: Please check link proper its not form submission its simple button you can try that run on any button

Comment: The form in that link have action to `actionpdf.php`. Form submission in my plugin is using ajax so there is no action for my from.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend fpdf for this super simple task.
Try https://wkhtmltopdf.org/

in your code it will be simple:

```
$htmlFileName = '/tmp/file.html';
$pdfFileName = '/tmp/file.pdf';
file_put_contents($htmlFileName, '<html>');
exec("wkhtmltopdf portrait $htmlFileName $pdfFileName");
```

Comment: This is a very minimal response. Could you provide more detail?

Comment: This is the thing, you don't really need anything else.

Comment: What are `$html`  and `$content`?